# OpenJPA: Assign a sequence generated value to ID if null

Tags: sequence, openjpa

I am using jpa for persisting my database along with java pojos

```
@Entity  
@Table(schema = "CENTRALSERVICES", name = "APPLICATION")
public class Application { 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 128)  
    private long id;  
}
```

My database is like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE  CENTRALSERVICES.APPLICATION(
 id bigint(8) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

The problem is that each application object that I persist was having an Id till now, but the requirement changed and now its not guaranteed if Id will be there. I saw something with sequence but I want to assign a sequence generated value only when the Id is null.
How to solve this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I changed my database schema and now my primary key is autogenerated whereas id for my application object I have created another field which can be null.